# How to add a custom endpoint to spring authorization server?

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I am trying to add a Pushed Authorization Request endpoint to Spring Authorization Server and as this [comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/1017#issuecomment-1363122691) I have [created](https://github.com/darkedges/spring-authorization-server-par/blob/main/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L85-L86)

When I try and access that endpoint, via a POST Request, it redirects me to a login URL. Enabling debug says I need to enable CSRF, but I am confused as if I issue a Client Credential request I dont need to have CSRF enabled.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit of code in your sample, so it is hard to be certain. It looks as though you are adding a new endpoint to the existing filter chain (`authServerSecurityFilterChain`) used for protocol endpoints. In that case, you need to ensure that your endpoint is excluded from CSRF protection, as by default only built-in endpoints are excluded. See `OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http)`, which uses `csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(...)`.

Note that you can also just use regular `@RestController`s in your Spring Boot application if you want to, you don't have to implement endpoints the same way SAS does. Endpoints are only implemented as filters/converters/authentication providers in the framework so that any servlet-based application could use it.

Comment: Thanks. I am just trying to follow the example given by the developer of SAS and failing. If I make a client credential request it does not have an issue with CSRF being enabled. The end point I am creating should be added to the OAuth framework as PAR is a new endpoint.

Comment: "If I make a client credential request it does not have an issue with CSRF being enabled." This is because the framework excludes the `/oauth2/token` endpoint from CSRF. You will need to do the same with your custom endpoint.